# Node.js express static server hangs on images- Chrome only

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, express

This is a really strange bug that has been bothering me for ages. I have a basic website that uses Express Static middleware in addition to separate routes that render Jade.

Here's my config

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(stylus.middleware({
    src      : __dirname + '/public',
    dest        : __dirname + '/public',
    compile : function(str, path)
    {
        return stylus(str)
        .set('filename', path)
        .set('compress', true) 
        .use(nib())
    }
}));


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(session({ secret: conf.sessionSecret, 
                        store: new RedisStore(),
                        saveUninitialized: true,
                        resave: true
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```

Here's my issue. After precisely 5 refreshes in a single tab in Chrome, image files refuse to load. All other content is fine, just images and just in Chrome. In order to remedy this, you have to open a new tab. I've tested this in Firefox as well- no issues. This error doesn't just happen in this application- it's happened in many of  my others as well.

As this project is currently in development, I'd rather not put in online as an example. Rest assured, this is completely reproducible. Any ideas?

UPDATE: I updated to Express 4 on the slim chance that updating might fix my issue. It did not. You can see a screen cast I made of the issue [here](https://www.screenr.com/XjON).

UPDATE: To test if the issue was with static server, I modified my code to be like this:

```
app.get('/img/*', function (req,res)
{
    console.log(req.url);
    console.log(path.extname(req.url));
    if (imgExt.indexOf(path.extname(req.url)) != -1)
    {
        res.sendfile('./public/'+req.url);
    }
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```

This had no effect, so I'm thinking this issue is either client-side or a bug with Chrome.

Comment: Try to see what happens in the Chrome development tools on the Network tab - you should see something related to the images.

Comment: I am building a CMS in Node.js and experiencing the same problem with Express 4.5.1 and express.static. I tested with Firefox (OK) and Chrome (fails after 5-7 page loads).

No exceptions in my logs and Chrome console's network log just seems to indicate that it is waiting for the server to respond to the image requests...

Comment: Take out everything napped to `/public` (the stylus stuff) but the `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))`. Let's verify that is working first.

Comment: I don't have enough to go on for sure, but based on the type of behavior and the magic number of times to refresh, this sounds like it could be an issue with browser's limit on the number of concurrent connections to a single domain. If some other part of your code is using too many connections, that could potentially prevent the image from loading. That said, I would expect the connections to be reset on page refresh, so I don't know specifically what could be wrong.

Comment: @JoshC. Took out the Stylus middleware. Same outcome.

Comment: After removing it from my code, Socket.io does not appear to be the issue.

Comment: @arghbleargh It seems like that is, in fact, the issue I'm encountering https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=85323 is there any way I can guarantee a closed connection?

Comment: You could try cleaning up resources using the `beforeunload` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload. However, it would be best to understand exactly the underlying problem. Can you give more details about how your client code works, especially regarding parts of it that could be issuing network requests? Also, tell us what pending requests you see in the Network tab when the hanging behavior is happening.

Comment: The website doesn't do anything overly complicated. I'm compiling the HTML with Jade, and serving it with res.render per my Express config. Client side I have some socket.io scripts but removing them didn't have an impact. I'm doing some AJAX requests once the page loaded but they all grab JSON.

In my head tag I have a couple of Google Web Fonts; Bootstrap, Font Awesome and jQuery through CDNs, moment.js, and underscore.

This isn't the only project where this has happened to me, but I can't find any common elements between them.

Comment: @arghbleargh Here's a normal request http://i.imgur.com/kl3k5G1.png and a stalled one http://i.imgur.com/fugZukd.png I appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: I have the same, the only way is to close chrome tab and reopen the new one..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours upon hours of debugging, I discovered this legacy bit of code buried in my servers.

```
app.get('/favicon.ico', function (req, res)
{
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'} );
});
```

It was intended to prevent the double requests for a favicon by an older version of Express. Obviously I forgot to call res.end() at the end. What boggles my mind is that neither Firefox nor Internet Explorer kept this connection alive between refreshes, while Chrome did. I appreciate the dialogue everybody!

Comment: This question popped into my feed - so might as well post this as reasoning: https://github.com/benjamingr/favicon-bug

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a chrome bug, based on it only being in chrome (and not firefox).

To fix it, I would try:

1. Try [Chrome Canary](http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html)
2. Lowering your timeout:

   server.on('connection', function(socket) {
      console.log("A new connection was made by a client.");
      socket.setTimeout(30 * 1000); 
    })

Comment: Neither of those made a difference. :\

Answer (score 0):

This could help too:

I has a mixed folder of images and html5 videos which I had mounted to serve. It was the videos that made all the requests hang as serve-static steams the whole file.

To prevent this issue I had to serve the videos seperately using middleware before mounting the folder.

Hope this helps someone too